# R.menu in eclipse error

Tags: java, android

[image]

I looked around a lot on how to fix the problem and still have not yet found a solution.

When i create a new Android Project i go through the whole process following the guide [located here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

This is a brand new eclipse download with the right plugins and software installed.

There errors occur here

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

saying R cannot be resolved as a type. I know not to import android.R but it has something to deal with the R file that is suppose to be generated when created.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Go to Window > Show View > Problems  
That will open a new container that will show you what's causing your app to fail to build, which is why your resource ID's are not accessible.

Comment: If you copy in the files then they will not be autogenerated into R, you have to go in and modify the file, and asve.

Comment: I have the problems container open (in the picture) just says what i already stated and does not help that much

Answer (score 2):

An error in XML build can result in destroying R file. but as far as I can see, your project doesn't seem to have any error in Resources.
so right click on project -> properties -> Android -> check if you have a Project build target selected. not selecting a target might be the problem.

And don't forget to CLEAN the project.

Comment: Yes selected is Android 4.4.2

Comment: Well then try one of these.

Try removing Android.R imports. and import it again.
Try Right Click on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.
Remember to check that all the resources are in small letters.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no errors in your XML files (layout, menu, strings, ...). If these files contain errors Eclipse will not be able to build the R file, which causes this behaviour.
Also sometimes something internally goes wrong in either Eclipse or the Android plugin, in which case a project clean is necessary (project -> clean projects). If that doesn't work, try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: it doesn't look like there are any errors. I don't know so much of XML and how it is suppose to be formatted though.

Comment: Well the default XML files should work. Have you tried my other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah i cleaned the projects and then restarted did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem as you ... try to delete the whole **menu** file and create it again :)

and just for make sure that you really dont have any bad code in your xml ... try it with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
          android:title="Preferences" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

where is R.java file? When you create new activity ID automatically generated in R.java file but your project doesn't have that file. That's why you are facing that problem. As i see your gen folder is empty.